# Which headless browser should i use with node.js in this case? or.. How do i loop only a part of a horseman.js (phantom for node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I need to do this:
1- load a page
2- login
3- simulate clicks/navigate
4- count elements
5- type things
In node.js.

I did already tried horseman.js and some scraping tools, like jsdom and cheerio for example, but I need to do it separately, first login only one time, and after that I need to do a specific navigation in looping, but node-horseman wont let me do something like:

```
//login function
function LoginOneTime (id, password){
   var horseman = new Horseman();

   horseman.open(url)
      .type(id)
      .type(password)
      .click(login button)
      .wait()

     return horseman;
}

var browser = new Horseman();
browser = LoginOneTime();
do{
browser.... //my looping navigation
}while(foo<bar)
```

So, I need or (preferably) somehow to do something like that with horseman, login one time and turn part of the navigation into a loop.. or I'll need another headless browser or framework/module that allows me to do that..

Thanks for your atention and time, and sorry any english errors! :)

Comment: You could do this one at a time (asynchronously) and remove cookies on each iteration (i.e. `.cookies()`).